# nodejs: When should I use `setImmediate(cb)` vs `cb()`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async.js, setimmediate

When reading on [The Callback Hell](https://www.airpair.com/node.js/posts/top-10-mistakes-node-developers-make#4-the-christmas-tree-of-callbacks-callback-hell-) , I came across two different ways of calling a callback function in the exact same example linked above (last example in the linked section):

```
cb();
```

and then

```
setImmediate(cb);
```

for seemingly exactly the same thing. When do I use which of the two versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `setImmediate` you are posticipating the execution of the callback to the end of the event loop. What does that mean? Nodejs will handle the other functions calls **before** your cb.

Comment: With "handle the other functions calls before your cb" you mean that in `setImmediate(cb); a(); b(); c();`, the functions `a`, `b` and `c` are being executed before `cb`?

Comment: If `a`, `b` and `c` are asynchronous then yes.

Comment: When `setImmediate(cb);` is called, it will be entered in the 'uv__loop'. When all the function calls in the 'uv__loop' got executed then the execution of the callback in setImmediate will be resumed. In uv__loop the priority is: 1. Normal Callback functions 2. SetImmediate functions  3. Timer functions

Comment: @LakshmiSwethaG Adding your comment to my answer.